# How do I change a donation amount down the road?

Tags: django, paypal

I'm building a website to allow people to donate to a local charity quickly and easily. The charity allows direct donations, but it's primary function is to do "per mile" style donations, but with pull ups. In that past, they have collected the pledges ("I'll pay $1 per pull up"), then manual contacted people for payment after the event. This isn't very slick and very time consuming.

What I'd like to be able to do is collect a pledge and payment information, then charge people automatically after the event. From what I've seen, I should put a hold/authorization on their account, then capture it with the appropriate amount after the event. But reauthorizing will only allow up to 115% of the original, and I can't very well just authorize a large amount and let it sit for two months before reauthorizing and capturing it.

I know this can be done, but I haven't messed with this side of things before, and the REST API from paypal doesn't have an obvious solution. Is there something I'm missing? Should I be going about this a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reference transactions.  I would recommend sticking with the Classic API for now, though.  REST isn't as mature yet and doesn't have all the same functionality quite yet.

So in the classic API you would use [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) and/or [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-pro/).  You can process an original authorization and then simply void it, or use the [card verification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDPGettingStarted/#cardverifications) process with Payments Pro.

You won't need to capture an original amount, so you won't need to worry about the 115% cap on the capture.

Instead, you'll use the [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=doreferencetransaction) API to process any amount you need to at any time from that user's account account.

With Express Checkout you have to be sure to include a billing agreement in the setup.  [This guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/) outlines that whole process.

With Payments Pro you just do the original card verification / auth and then pass that auth ID into the DoReferenceTransaction API.

In either case, if you're working with PHP this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make all of the API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Awesome! Gonna test this out and report back.

Comment: Just realized I never followed up. It's working just fine. Thank you!